# Propose a synthesis of indane from benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

The question is to propose a synthesis of indane from benzene. I started by the following. The black box is what I am not sure about. I know that the stable carbocation should be the middle one, this is why I am not sure. I need help here.

[image]

Comment: Better to do Friedel–Crafts acylation chemistry, then get rid of the carbonyl groups later, that avoids the problem which you pointed out

Comment: Related: [Double alkylation of benzene to form tetralin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/41326/16683)

Comment: If you treat your bromo alkyl compound with AIBN/tributyltinhydride it should cyclise to your product by a radical mechanism

Comment: @Waylander I'm not seeing it - that would give you a compound with two hydrogens too many, I think

Comment: @Waylander https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8xYd.jpg

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. Reflux this product over activated MnO2 to get the required

Comment: I still haven't taken this reaction (AIBN) so i don't think i can use it. 
I did another way:
1- Fridlecraft with Cl-Ch2-Ch2-Cl
2- Mg/ether to prepare my grignard reagent 
3- Co2 
4- H+ ; the benzene ring will attack the carboxyl group
5-Reduce by clemmenson 

My concern is step 1 and 4

Comment: Polyphosphoric acid is reagent of choice for step 4. Instead of Grignard + CO2 attack the chloride with KCN and hydrolyse to get the acid.

Comment: Why doesn't grignard work though :( ?

Comment: It would, you can after all buy phenethyl magnesium chloride. But as a general principle for more complex molecules the cyanide + hydrolysis is a better option

Comment: Just saying: there’s a carbon missing in the product of the first step.

Comment: another way would be to (1) Friedel-Craft acylation with succinic anhydride/$AlCl_3$ (2)Clemmenson reduction (3) $H_3PO_4$ (4) Clemmenson reduction.

Comment: Succinic anhydride has too many carbon atoms, your route will give tetralin

Comment: @Waylander Potentially a naive question from an inorganic chemist: Is such reaction with AIBN/Sn known to happen like that? It looks like you will be breaking the Ph ring aromaticity. Can you provide a reference where someone has done something similar ?  Just being curious, thank you.

Comment: Now that I'm looking I can't find a ref, Possibly I have mis-remembered but I no longer have Scifinder access to check.

Comment: Do people actually do Clemmensen reductions these days or is this paper chemistry?

Comment: @Beerhunter This is what i found interesting with this question. How would you actually do it in the lab. The first step in the reaction is fine (got a ref for it) but for the second i am not sure the Br will survive the highly acidic and reducing conditions of the clemmensen reduction. Or in the case of AIBN (which is a reasonable suggestion btw) not sure if you will get the cyclized product or a dimer or both.

Comment: The synthesis proposed could be fine if reordered and a step removed. Acylation occurs as presented. Add some more Lewis acid (notwithstanding a calorimetry check first), then cyclise to give the 1-indanone. Then reduce last using your favourite reduction method. The two I've witnessed industrially are a) TFA with triethylsilane or tetramethyldisiloxane, b) methanesulfonic acid with 5% Rhodium catalyst and hydrogenation at 60 bar. Both work on benzoyl groups really well.

Comment: @Beerhunter, I surmise it is simply that old reactions such as the Clemmensen are traditionally taught early on.

Answer (score 6):

To prepare indane (**6**) from benzene, make the procedure as simple as possible and amenable to scale-up. Propiophenone (**2**) is readily available by Friedel-Crafts acylation of benzene with propionyl chloride (**1**). Removal of the carbonyl group of propiophenone and the creation of a carboxyl moiety can be achieved via the Willgerodt reaction to produce amide **3**. Vigorous  acid or base cleavage of the amide is possible but nitrous acid affords a mild route to carboxylic acid **4**. One can use the AlCl<sub>3</sub> F-C route again but hot polyphosphoric acid is a clean method for the intramolecular acylation without having to form the acid chloride. Finally, Clemmensen reduction of indanone (**5**) gives indane (**6**). Wolff-Kishner reduction is also a good option for the final step.

[image]

Comment: Nice one,  this Willgerodt reaction (unknown to me till now) was the missing link to the type of synthesis i was trying to get at as well!

Comment: @AMM: I should add that the initially formed product in the formation of amide 3 is the thioamide, which undergoes hydrolysis under reaction conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a suggested route for synthesizing indane starting from benzene and allyl bromide. I appreciate that this may not be a desirable answer for a school question but it is how one could perform the synthesis in real life and is based on high yield reactions that have been previously reported (see references, also note that this may not be the most efficient way):

[image]

References:
1) Synlett, 1999, No. 8, 1245.
2) J Org. Chem. Vol.78, No 19, 9772.
3) J Org. Chem. Vol.57, No 23, 1992.
4) Molecules 2014, Vol 19, No 5, 5599.
5) Catalysis letters 2011, Vol 141, No 4. 507.

Comment: Be quicker to do a Heck with your bromobenzene and acrylate.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking of cross coupling approaches too and specifically converting the benzene to PhB(OH)2 and then suzuki coupling but didn't want to use transition metals or 'uncommon' ligands for this one and keep it more 'organic'. The Heck is a reasonable suggestion though. I assume you would follow with hydrogenation of the double bond and hydrolysis to get the acid afterwards ?

Comment: Exactly so, then polyphosphoric acid for the cyclisation

Answer (score 0):

I think the effeicient and better way to synthesize the given compound with greater yield from Benzene may be this,
[image]

Comment: I dont think this is a good way since you will get a mixture of all possible Friedel Crafts products such as PhCH2CH2CH2Ph etc.

Comment: Not if you add benzene into the mixture or use a lanthanide Lewis acid in a flow system with a dichloropropane and benzene feed in the appropriate ratio.

Comment: @Beerhunter This doesn't sound very practical and i cant find it in the literature. It does sound very interesting though. Can you provide a reference please as it might be of use to me in general (it doesn't have to be exactly the same reaction)? Thank you.

Comment: The concept will have been demonstrated, but not necessarily on exactly the same compounds. The literature is just what other people have done, which doesn't always make it the best way to do something. The methodology of using something like scandium triflate has been demonstrated.  Using flow chemistry to control stoichiometry has been also.

Comment: Yes, this is why i asked for something similar and not the same so I could have a look into it. Indeed, literature is not necessarily the best way to do something but it is in many cases the fastest and safest way compared to re-inventing the wheel. The fact that something makes sense as a concept is very far from actually working in the lab. There has been plenty occasions where people in the lab tried to take a 'shortcut' but ended up spending much more time compared to performing a few more, but well established, reactions. As far as i am concerned, what you suggest might or might not work.

Comment: This route is problematic: 1) alkylation of benzene via F-C gives products that are more reactive than benzene; 2) polymerization here is a problem IF the primary carbocation were the reacting species; 3) n-propyl chloride gives isopropylbenzene. Rearrangement of the primary to the the secondary carbocation occurs.  Expect the same problem here.

Comment: @AMM I don't disagree in the slightest.  There are a lot of paper reactions thrown around as working, when in fact they don't. We - as a community - should also think outside of the round bottom flask.  It amazes me that unpleasant and hazardous reagents ate still being lectured as the go to ones for simple transformations.