# Synthesis of a Substituted Indane

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

From the starting reactants given as the sole carbon source:

[image]

We need to synthesis the following compound (we can use any inorganic reagents).

[image: 4-(1-bromo-2-methylpropyl)-2,3-dihydro-1H-indene]

Here is what I tried so far, but I don't think it looks "realistic"

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is yet another exmple of a poorly thought out question that bears no resemblence to real world chemistry. I presume the question setter wants to see F-C alkylation with the di-bromopropane to set up the indane ring. The reality is that this will mostly give the products of rearrangement.

Comment: see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91606/propose-a-synthesis-of-indane-from-benzene

Comment: There is a difficulty with your last step. There are 3 possible benzylic sites for bromination and I think you will get a mixture. I would reduce the ketone to the benzylic alcohol and treat with PBr3

Comment: The reaction of the Grignard with bromobenzene is not going to do what you want and displace the Br. I would trap the Grignard with borate ester and couple that with the bromobenzene under Pd catalysis.

Comment: @Waylander "This is yet another example of..." are you talking about the OP's questions (I only see one at the moment) or are you lumping this question with those by other users and using your comment to rant against "them"? Your comment seems to me to be *deliberately unwelcoming* to a new user and to use the space under their first question to talk about things that belong in chat or meta. "Poorly thought out" may be true, but the "yet another example of" is gratuitous and unhelpful, and potentially discouraging. Let's use the space under a new user's first question to be more welcoming."

Comment: @uhoh my rant is directed at the setter of the question the OP is attempting to answer

Comment: @Waylander who it seems will not be a recipient; so perhaps, no longer needed?

Comment: @uhoh as that comment is quoted in the answer I'm leaving it up

Comment: @Waylander okay, one could argue that since the information is now captured in an answer it no longer needs to be there as well... It's no longer *helping* the page...

Answer (score 4):

I'll be frank about it....you can't get there from here! In @Waylander's words " This is ...a poorly thought out question...". Allow me to pose the question as it should have been asked.  How does one synthesize 5-(1-bromo-2-methylpropyl)-2,3-dihydro-1H-indene **1** from benzene, propionic acid, and isobutyric acid?

[image]

Inspection of ketone **2** shows that a Friedel-Crafts acylation of indane **3** does not occur at $\ce{C4}$ but rather at $\ce{C5}$. The synthesis of bromide **1** from ketone **2** requires reduction to a benzylic alcohol (*e. g.*; $\ce{NaBH4/C2H5OH}$) followed by treatment with $\ce{HBr}$. Isobutyric acid and propionic acid are readily converted to their respective acyl chlorides with $\ce{SOCl2}$. As to the preparation of indane from benzene, [this issue has been addressed previously on ChemSE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91606/propose-a-synthesis-of-indane-from-benzene/91753#91753).